# How can I configure and enable DHCP Server inside the VirtualBox?

Tags: dhcp-server

I've installed Debian 9.0 inside the [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox).

I want to disable VirtualBox's DHCP Server and configure this Debian image as DHCP-Server, so that other images inside the Virtualbox can get their IP addresses from my Debian DHCP-Server.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Disable NAT-Networking and use Bridged or internal networking. Here are the [docs](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for more details.

The important thing is that you use a shared virtual network for the server and client hosts and disable the virtualbox DHCP server.

Comment: This actually IS the answer. When you configure Virtualbox to have a shared network between guests (either internal or bridged mode), you can run a dhcp server in one guest VM and other VMs can receive IPs from it. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html for more details on VirtualBox network modes.

Comment: I know how to do it myself, how about everyone else, that doesn't know.  You should provide specifics.

Comment: What specifics are missing?

Comment: If somebody knew nothing about VirtualBox, does your answer by itself, answer the author's question?

Comment: I guess somebody asking the question is using Virtualbox. And may be able to find the settings dialog. Somebody able to setup a dhcp server will not be a total noob as well. So what is missing for you, with this answer when you opened the VirtualBox network dialog looking for how to change the network type?